# How to continue processing code after an error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I tried the following:

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line, col, err) {
    return true
}
```

It only prevents the error from being shown in the console, however, the code stops being processed.

I want the browser to ignore the error and continue processing the next line, so in the following code:

```
alert(IDontExist);
alert("Hello");
```

The second alert should pop up, although there is a ReferenceError before it.

Update 1: `try...catch` is not the way to go here, because the problematic code will be external. So the code is more like:

inline HTML:

```
<script src="problematic.js"></script>
```

problematic.js

```
alert(UndefinedVariable);
alert("I am valid JS");
```

Here I want "I am valid JS" to pop up.

Comment: Overriding `window.error` will do you no good. When error is encountered, it will break the normal workflow and then using `window.error`, you will print it. Correct way is to put any such code inside `try...catch`

Comment: By using a try/catch?

Comment: Rajesh Andrew Li Unfortunately `try...catch` won't work here because the problematic code is external not inline.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your problematic function inside a `try-catch`

```
try{
    //Here you put the code that it could crash
    console.log("Trying to execute the function");
    problematicFunction();
    //If an error is found, the code will go to catch and stop the try execution
    console.log("I will never be executed! :c");
} catch(e){
    //And here you put what to do in case that you have an error
    console.log("Hey i'm a cool error!\n" + e);
}
console.log("Guess what? I still working :D");
```

Comment: The problematic code will be external, take a look at the update.